# Можно ли считать sleep(...) запрещенным методом?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня ситуация когда мне надо приостановить поток на некоторое время, но участия объекта-монитора не требуется, так как это служба которая не взаимодействует с другими потоками через lock объекты. Я хотел использовать `sleep`, но идея выдает worning.

```
try {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(10); // Shows references to static methods and fields via class instance rather than a class itself
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

В моем контексте вроде не критично, но я слышал что `sleep`, - это дурной тон и его лучше не использовать.

Есть ли необходимость специально добавлять синхронизацию для того чтобы обеспечить ожидание службы при помощи `wait()` или так тоже можно, и код в котором используется `sleep` можно считать корректным?

Comment: sleep плохо в главном треде (особенно, если там ещё gui крутится). А если это второстепенный поток, задача которого раз в минуту послать сигнал - то все нормально.

Comment: Вы warning читали? Он про вызов статического метода у инстанса объекта, а не у класса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уберите `.currentThread()` и **IDEA** перестанет ругаться. А так **sleep** можно использовать, главное не усыплять важные потоки, такие как The Event Dispatch Thread (swing), JavaFX Application thread (он же UI thread) и подобные.